How do I use two functions in power apps?
How do I use two functions in power apps?
I have a button that needs to be displayed if two criteria are met.
I tried using And, &, &&. I have no clue what’s wrong.
I have two text boxes that need to be filled in before the submit button is active.
So my current formula is
If(IsBlank(textinput1.text),displaymode.disabled,displaymode.edit) AND If(IsBlank(textinput2.text),displaymode.disabled,displaymode.edit)

The AND part is wrong. But I don't know why. Please help

You have 4 open-parentheses and no close-parentheses; I'd start by addressing that.

Great was just a typo. Corrected it in my comment. I’m Missing the part in your response on how to use two IF statements. Thanks

Why do you "need" 2 IF functions?  Why not 1 with an expression that is the AND of your 2 criteria?

The problem with your code is you have two expressions which result in DisplayMode property. So in the backend, your code is executing like this:
E.g. If both text_fileds are blank, then the output of your expressions after evaluating each if statements are:

Displaymode.Edit && Displaymode.Edit

which doesn't make any sense ryt! because you can't evaluate the result now as these are properties, not an expression to evaluate. Hence you need to combine both of them into a single one as below:
If(IsBlank(textinput1.text) || IsBlank(textinput2.text), 
    Displaymode.Disabled,
    Displaymode.Edit
) 


Thank you so ,much! But ok I actually need both text boxes to be filled in before the submit button is active. With this formula, the submit button is actrive if they fill in at least one of the boxes. Any suggestions?

I have updated the answer, instead of And (&&) you need to put Or (||)

YAY THANK YOU <333333333333
